# Gradle can't copy binary file resources (jpg) in project build

Tags: gradle

I have included a binary image needed for my Spring Boot tests as /src/main/resources/img/CEO.jpg

When I try to build the project ("gradle build") I get this error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript29.groovy: 1: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 1, column 10.
   out.print("""����JFIF��(ExifMMV(1f�in�HHPicasa�0220����ޤ !�e7877ee2da2aa6570000000000000000R980100J(Z�HH����JFIF��C
```

It is like if the binary content of the file is messing around with Gradle as it tries to copy it as if it was text when executing the "grade build" command. Without this file everything works ok (I have tried with other binary files and all fail). It seems Gradle only handles text files. Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem probably lies in the fact that during `build` gradle not just copies the files but try to filter them. It happens usually during `processResources` task. What you need to do is to alter the task in such a way that it copies this file but does not filter it.

Comment: Thanks but can you give any directions on how to customise that task? Thanks.

Comment: Actually you've given too little details. More or less you need sth like this: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/c2c39deba32442b1349da92876f1f816